# How to change template instantiate order?

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, instantiation, generic-programming

I want to change the instantiate order of the overload templates. My code are as follow:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;
template<typename T>
struct Base
{

};
template<typename T>
struct Derived:Base<T>
{

};

//template 1
template<typename T1>
void f(Base<T1>& a){
    cout<<"in 1\n";
}

//template 2
template<typename T2>
void f(T2 b){
    cout<<"in 2\n";
}

int main(){
    Derived<int> v1;
    f(v1);
}
```

The compiler will chose template 2 as default, but I want it to chose template 1.

Comment: `f<int>(v1)`, don't let it find the template for you... Template instanciation rules are sometimes surprising if you let the compiler infer the types.

Comment: You have to use SFINAE or tag dispatching, or specify which function to call at call site.

Comment: You should detail on what you want to do with `b` in template 2 and what arguments you *want* to allow. There are easy solutions that involve no tag dispatching, SFINAE or traits if all you want to do is to print `"in 2"`.

Comment: If you remove template 2 the compiler will choose template 1. Presumably there's more to the question than that, but you have to say more about what it is that you want to do.

Answer (score 1):

The right term for this is overload resolution preferences, and second overload is chosen because it is a better match. It appeared to be more challenging than I expected to put together a code which would make sure proper overload was selected. Here it is:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
struct Base { };
template<typename T>
struct Derived:Base<T> { };

template <class T>
struct template_argument { using type = void*; };

template <template <class > class T, class ARG>
struct template_argument<T<ARG> > { 
    using type = ARG;
};

template <class T>
using template_argument_t = typename template_argument<T>::type;

template<typename T1>
void f(Base<T1>& ){
    std::cout << "Base-expecting f called\n";
}

template<class T>
void f(T, std::enable_if_t<!std::is_base_of<Base<template_argument_t<T> >, T>::value>* = nullptr ) {
    std::cout << "Generic f was called.\n";
}

template <class T>
struct Z { };

int main(){
    Derived<int> v1;

    f(v1);
    f(int() );
    f(Z<int>() );
}
```

Output:

> Base-expecting f called
>
> Generic f was called.
>
> Generic f was called.

Comment: @Jarod42, care to look at this version? I believe, it is working as expected.

Comment: Don't know what OP expects for `struct OtherDerived : Base<int> {};`.

Comment: @Jarod42, neither do I for sure, but I suspect, they would want the first overload?

Comment: Your would provide `"Generic f"`, mine would provide `"Base-expecting f"`.

Answer (score 1):

With custom traits

```
template <typename T> std::true_type derive_from_base_impl(const Base<T>*);
std::false_type derive_from_base_impl(...);

template <typename T>
using derive_from_base = decltype(derive_from_base_impl(std::declval<T*>()));

static_assert(!derive_from_base<int>::value, "");
static_assert(derive_from_base<Derived<int>>::value, "");
```

And SFINAE, you may do

```
template<typename T>
void f(Base<T>& a) { std::cout << "in 1\n"; }

template<typename T>
std::enable_if_t<!derive_from_base<T>::value>
f(T b) { std::cout << "in 2\n"; }
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/05637697533c6f5e)

Comment: @SergeyA: with a custom traits.

Comment: I have put together another version, which it is a bit more generic - it doesn't check for particular Base and Derived. Care to take a look?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is quite simple, all you have to do is prevent the second template to be instantiated for a certain class, which can be done quickly using `std::enable_if_t` from the type_traits header:

Template 2 becomes this, and Template 1 remains unchanged

```
//template 2
template<typename T2, std::enable_if_t<!std::is_base_of<Base<T2>, T2>::value>>
void f(T2 b) {
    cout << "in 2\n";
}
```

Comment: It is a little more complex than that: `Derived<int>` inherits from `Base<int>`, not from `Base<Derived<int>>`.

Answer (score -1):

Provide an argument that has a better match:

```
int main(){
    Derived<int> v1;
    f(v1); // in 2
    f((Base<int>&)v1); // in 1
}
```

In this case 
`f(v1)` will resolve to `f<Base<int>>(v1)`

and `f((Base<int>&)v1)` to `f<int>(v1)`

Comment: or `f<Base<int>>(v1)`.

Comment: it is certainly **not** the same.